# Create event based on dates in a text field

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, calendar, eventkit

How can I create an event with the iPhone's calendar, getting the start and end dates from a `UITextField`?

Comment: Do you mean a `UITextField`? How did the text get into the `UILabel`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create new event in calendar from UITextField?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322184/create-new-event-in-calendar-from-uitextfield)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add an event programmatically, read Apple's [Event Kit Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html). Maybe you want to make it easier on yourself by using an `EKEventViewController`, but you can do everything in code as well.

To transform an `NSString` from the `text` property of your text field into an `NSDate` you will have to use an `NSDateFormatter`. There are good examples in the [class documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: could you provide some sample code as I'm a bit lost? :| thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
//create an EKEventEditViewController to display the event view controller.

EKEventEditViewController *addController = [[EKEventEditViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

//set eventstore global reference

addController.eventStore = self.eventStore;

// present EventsAddViewController as a modal view controller
[self presentModalViewController:addController animated:YES];

// assign <EKEventEditViewDelegate> to view controller
    addController.editViewDelegate = self;
[addController release];

//======================================================================

//Add delegate methods

- (void)eventEditViewController:(EKEventEditViewController *)controller 
    didCompleteWithAction:(EKEventEditViewAction)action {

NSError *error = nil;
EKEvent *thisEvent = controller.event;

switch (action) {
    case EKEventEditViewActionCanceled:
        // Edit action canceled, do nothing. 
        break;

    case EKEventEditViewActionSaved:
        // When user hit "Done" button, save the newly created event to the event store, 

        [controller.eventStore saveEvent:controller.event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&error];
        break;

    case EKEventEditViewActionDeleted:
        // When deleting an event, remove the event from the event store, 

        [controller.eventStore removeEvent:thisEvent span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&error];
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
// Dismiss the modal view controller
[controller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}

// Set the calendar edited by EKEventEditViewController to our chosen calendar - the default calendar.

- (EKCalendar *)eventEditViewControllerDefaultCalendarForNewEvents:(EKEventEditViewController *)controller 
{
EKCalendar *calendarForEdit = self.defaultCalendar;
return calendarForEdit;
}
```